# Are there arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions in every increasing sequence of positive integers with bounded gaps between consecutive terms?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I cannot find the exact same question asked anywhere in this site. I know the related Green-Tao theorem but the gaps between consecutive primes can grow unbounded so it does not seem helpful to answer this question.
What I have tried: assume the largest gap is D and without loss of generality it appears infinitely often. Then I try to apply the pigeonhole principle but don't know how.
Thanks in advance.

Added thought: will there always be a subsequence forming an infinitely long arithmetic progression in the original sequence? I think the answer is NO.

Comment: Your set has positive density, hence Szemerédi's theorem applies, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem

Comment: If the gaps are bounded, say by $T$, a much easier Van der Varden theorem also helps: color $n$ to color $i\in \{1,\ldots,T\} $ if $nT+i$ belongs to your set and find a large monochromatic progression.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I suggest that you turn your comment into an answer so that this question can be closed.

Comment: @GHfromMO ok, done

Comment: @GHfromMO, usually we close a question so that it cannot be answered. It seems odd to answer a question so that it can be closed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson closed in good sense:)

Comment: Yes, I meant "closed in a good sense". Like "case closed". I think the question was fine for this site, even though to combinatorics experts it was probably rather standard.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to edit in a new question several months after you have accepted an answer to the original question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is it better to start a new question? I edited the existing one because the two questions are so similar but the answers are different.

Comment: My opinion: yes, better to ask a new question. Be sure to link each of the two questions to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may of course use Szemeredi theorem, as suggested by Alexander Kalmynin.

If you need a more elementary argument, you may apply Van der Waerden theorem as follows: assuming that the gaps are bounded by $T$, color every positive integer $n$ to the color $i\in \{1,\dots,T\}$ if $nT+i$ belongs to your set (so each large enough integer gets at least one color), and find a large monochromatic arithmetic progression. It corresonds to a large progression in the initial set.

Comment: Let $S$ be the OP's set. I think we can simply define the color of a positive integer $n$ as $\min\{i\geq 1:n+i\in S\}$. By assumption, the color of each $n$ is bounded by $T$, so we used finitely many colors. By van der Waerden's theorem, there is an arbitrary long arithmetic progression $P$ which is monochromatic. If the color of $P$ is $i$, then $P+i$ is a long arithmetic progression in $S$.