# Are there infinitely long arithmetic progressions in every increasing sequence of positive integers with bounded gaps between consecutive terms?

Tags: integer-sequences, arithmetic-progression

Suppose the largest gap is D>1 and at least two of the gaps 1,2,...,D appear infinitely many times. I think the answer is NO. But I find it difficult to formulate a necessary and sufficient condition for the sequence to have an infinitely long arithmetic progression.
A related question is [about the existence of finite arithmetic progressions of any given length k](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405252/are-there-arbitrarily-long-arithmetic-progressions-in-every-increasing-sequence) and the answer is YES.

Comment: Do you mean arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions or do you mean such a set must include all terms of the form $a + kd$ for some $a,d$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao I mean the second, the infinite set {a+kd: k \in N}. The finite arithmetic progression version has been addressed in the linked question.

Comment: I think it suffices to take a Sturmian word and interpret its symbols as gaps of lengths 1 and 2...

Comment: The obvious random construction will almost surely produce a counterexample. Baire category argument also works.

Comment: Doesn't this simple idea work? Enumerate the positive increasing arithmetic sequences (all initial values and step sizes) and at the nth step, select a term of the nth sequence; the first term that's more than 1 greater than the previous selected term. So, no consecutive numbers and intersects every infinite arithmetic sequence. The complement has gaps of size 1 and fails to contain any infinite arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known and easy to see (as in the old math.se question [An example showing that van der Waerden's theorem is not true for infinite arithmetic progressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487778/an-example-showing-that-van-der-waerdens-theorem-is-not-true-for-infinite-arith)) that $\mathbb N$ can be partitioned into two sets $A$ and $B$ neither of which contains an infinite arithmetic progression.

Plainly, for such $A$ and $B$, the set
$$\{2n:n\in A\}\cup\{2n+1:n\in B\}$$
has maximum gap $D=3$ and contains no infinite arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a set $S$ where the maximal gap is $D=2$ and which even is dense in the sense that
$$\forall \epsilon>0:\exists N_\epsilon>1: \forall N\geq N_\epsilon\wedge k>0 : \frac{\#([k+1,k+N]\cap S)}{ N}>1-\epsilon.,$$
but which contains no infinite arithmetic progression $\{a\,m +b: m\geq m_0\}.$

Denote by $\pi_a$ the $a$-th  prime, and by $T(p,a)$ the numbers recursively defined by
$$T(0,a)=\pi_a,~~T(p+1,a)~=~2^{T(p,a)}.$$
This construction ensures that for $(p_1,a_1)\neq(p_2,a_2)$, one has $T(p_1,a_1)\neq T(p_2,a_2)$.

For $p\geq1$ and $a>1$, there is exactly one  $c(p,a)\in [T(p,a),T(p,a)+a-1]$ with $c(p,a) \equiv p \mod a$, and these intervals are pairwise separated such that $|c(p_1,a_1)-c(p_2,a_2)|>1$ for  $(p_1,a_1)\neq(p_2,a_2)$.
Choosing
$$S~=~\mathbb{N} \backslash \{c(p,a): p\geq 1,a>1\},$$
therefore has maximal gap $D=2$ and because    each  arithmetic progression $\{a\,m +b: m\geq m_0\}$ contains infinitely many $c(p,a)$, the set $S$ contains no arithmetic progression.  $S$ is dense in the above sense because
$$\#([k+1,k+N]\cap S) \geq N-\log_2 N.$$

Comment: Per the statement $|c(p_1,a_1)-c(p_2,a_2)|>1$: what if we have a Mersenne prime and the corresponding adjacent power of two?  (Perhaps we are only considering odd $\pi_a$?)

Comment: @Bill Bradley: $a>1$ implies $\pi_a$ odd.

Comment: Can't you just enumerate the infinite arithmetic progressions, construct a very rapidly increasing sequence of numbers that meets all of them, and take the complement?

Comment: @bof: This is exactly what $c(p,a)$ is supposed to achieve :)